# How to convert Indic Characters to Unicode Escaped characters

Tags: javascript, php, android, json, utf-8

I am currently designing a mobile application for Android. The text and content are in the Local Indic Language, Tamil. For Welcome, the equivalent of Tamil translation is: `வணக்கம்`. Since Android cannot display Indic Text, I am converting it using a service called [JavaScript String Escape](http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html).

So this works in this way:

- **Input:** `வணக்கம்`
- **Output:** `\u0BB5\u0BA3\u0B95\u0BCD\u0B95\u0BAE\u0BCD`

How can I make this using JavaScript or PHP as I have huge loads of text to be converted and made it into JSON. Sample JSON:

```
{
  "title": "\u0BAE\u0BB0\u0BC1\u0BA4\u0BCD\u0BA4\u0BC1\u0BB5\u0BB0\u0BBF\u0BA9\u0BCD \u0BAA\u0BC6\u0BAF\u0BB0\u0BCD #1",
  "image": "http://www.exceptnothing.com/doctors/doc11.png",
  "rating": "\u2713 \u0B87\u0BAA\u0BCD\u0BAA\u0BC7\u0BBE\u0BA4\u0BC1 \u0BAA\u0BBE\u0BB0\u0BCD\u0B95\u0BCD\u0B95\u0BB2\u0BBE\u0BAE\u0BCD",
  "rating2": "",
  "releaseYear": "\u0BA8\u0BBE\u0BB3\u0BCD \u0BAE\u0BC1\u0BB4\u0BC1\u0BB5\u0BA4\u0BC1\u0BAE\u0BCD \u0BAA\u0BBE\u0BB0\u0BCD\u0B95\u0BCD\u0B95\u0BB2\u0BBE\u0BAE\u0BCD",
  "genre": ["\u25B6 \u0B87\u0BA4\u0BAF \u0BA8\u0BBF\u0BAA\u0BC1\u0BA3\u0BB0\u0BCD"]
}
```

I also would like to know how to decode the above JSON and show it as `வணக்கம்`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you need `escape()`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Is it that simple?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) in JavaScript and [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP. Open up your console and type the following:

```
escape("வணக்கம்")
```

And you will get the following back:

```
"%u0BB5%u0BA3%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BAE%u0BCD"
```

So the first one is solved. To get back the original `வணக்கம்` from the above one, use [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape):

```
unescape("%u0BB5%u0BA3%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BAE%u0BCD");
```

> ***Note:*** One thing to be noted is, both [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) and [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) are deprecated. So you need to use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent`

**Preview**

[image]

**Update for Server Side**

For encoding and decoding into JSON, it is better for you to use the PHP's built-in function. The same `escape()` can also be used in PHP as [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), they both give the same result.

```
json_encode("வணக்கம்");
=> "%u0BB5%u0BA3%u0B95%u0BCD%u0B95%u0BAE%u0BCD"
```

Also, see [JavaScript: Escaping Special Characters](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/) for more information. Hope this helps. `:)`

Comment: which is why you can use en/decodeURIComponent which is not deprecated