# Displaying Other Language Text On Android Application

Tags: android, string, api

I have developed an API in node js for mobile applications developed in android and iOS. One of the user of the app input the name as "ساجار" (arabic font) and it got stored in database as it is. The name is displayed as it is in the iOS app but the android app displays some junk. Can someone tell me if I need to make some changes in the API or something on the android app end and what is to be done?

Comment: the fonts might be missing

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477205/decoding-urdu-codes-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Use Escape Sequence characters. A tool like this: http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html can help you. It escapes the characters, example:

**ساجار -> \u0633\u0627\u062C\u0627\u0631**

Before submitting to database, you can submit it as Unicode escaped characters itself, so that no work would be needed in Android side.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921078/how-to-convert-indic-characters-to-unicode-escaped-characters).

Faced same problem, Used php to escape the characters and submit to database/JSON file. Let me know if you've any doubts.

Comment: I have implemented this currently but then I have to decode the unicode to text when I have to use it right? which is what I am doing currently

Comment: No, you need not have to decode it. exceptnothing.com/doctors.json Look at this, this is the JSON file I'm using for my app. Those JSON details gets parsed into a ListView. I do not decode it, it shows in the correct language. If still the language isn't shown, try using characters for a French word with accents, if that works fine, then Arabic font might be missing.

Comment: Depending upon the language, I never included a Tamil font, yet it as shown. I am not sure whether phones include Arabic font. Or if not, set custom font for the text view where the Arabic text will appear: www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/

Comment: Is the title value for example "\u0BAE\u0BB0\u0BC1\u0BA4\u0BCD\u0BA4\u0BC1\u0BB5\u0BB0\u0BBF\u0BA9\u0BCD \u0BAA\u0BC6\u0BAF\u0BB0\u0BCD #2" stored in the same unicode format in database?

Comment: I don't use Database mate. I use http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/, it parses the JSON to ListView.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using JSON, then you may need to change your request `content-type` header from

`"application/json"`

to

`"application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: The storing of data in database is working perfectly fine. It is about displaying it in the app.